# Does this Python expression make sense?

Tags: python, logic, expression

I found this kind of expression several times in a python program:

```
if variable is not None:
    dothings(variable)
```

It seems strange to me, and I think that it has no more sense than:

```
if variable:
    dothings(variable)
```

Maybe I don't know Python enough, and the expression is explained somewhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`variable` could be `0`, or `False`, or `[]`, or `()`; be 'falsy' in other words, and then the `if` statement would be skipped.

See [Truth testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for more detail on what is considered false in a boolean context.

In short, testing if `variable is not None` allows `variable` to be *anything else*, including values that would otherwise be considered False in a boolean context.

Comment: So, ....  "A `is not` B"  is different that "A is `not B`" and Python applies the former. Isn't it?

Comment: `is not` is the inverse of `is`, yes. See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in. You could also say `not A is B`.

Answer (score 5):

Some values are *falsy*, but are not `None`. You may still want to `dothings()` to those values.

[Here are the things that are *falsy* in Python 2.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) (You may want to change the '2' in the URL to a '3' to get the values for Python 3, but it didn't change much.)

Answer (score 1):

E.g.

```
i = 0

if i is not None:
    print i    # prints i

if i:
    print i    # prints nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

In the google voice python implementation I came across this as well, their use was during a function call. The parameters are defaulted to "None" and then when the function is called they can check if the values are changed or the default.
I.E.

```
def login (user=None, password=None)
  if user is None:
     user = input('Please enter your username');
  ...
  return <something>;
```

called by

```
login()
```

OR

```
login(user='cool_dude')
```

OR

any combination of user/password you wish.

Additionally your "update" of the logic implies that variable == true or false. That is not correct for all cases (it may work in some cases but I'm throwing them out, since it's not a general case). What you are testing by using the "NONE" logic is whether the variable contains anything besides NONE. Similar to what I was saying above, all the "login function" was doing was determining if the user passed anything, not whether the value was valid, true, etc.